# Ultrapower of a field is purely transcendental

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, lo.logic, model-theory, fields, ultrafilters

Let $F$ be a field, $I$ a set, and $U$ an ultrafilter on $I$. Is the ultrapower $\prod_U F$ a purely transcendental field extension of $F$?

According to Chapter VII, Exercise 3.6 from Barnes, Mack "An algebraic introduction to mathematical logic" the answer is apparently yes, but how does one actually show this?

I am happy to assume additional conditions on the ultrafilter if that helps.

Comment: A pretty trivial observation: the ultrapower clearly doesn't contain any nontrivial elements algebraic over $F$ - for any polynomial $p\in F[x]$, if $p(x)=0$ in the ultraproduct, then $p$ vanishes on infinitely many (hence on some) coordinate of $x$.

Comment: I'm confused: if $F$ is algebraically closed, then so is the ultrapower (it is elementarily equivalent). But I don't think any nontrivial purely transcendental extension  of any field is algebraically closed...

Comment: @TimCampion I've just noticed that as well - indeed, in a purely transcendental extension by elements $t_\alpha$, none of those elements has a square root. So a purely transcendental extension is not algebraically closed.

Comment: Might it be that all the exercise is asking is that any element of the ultrapower algebraic over $F$ is already in $F$?

Comment: @TimCampion Thank you! I guess this means that the exercise is simply false. I wonder what the authors intended... They state clearly "Prove that $K$ is a purely transcendental extension of $F$."

Comment: The exercise states "$K$ is a *pure* transcendental extension". Though the authors never specify what they mean, perhaps Andres' interpretation is right.

Comment: Just for the record, in my answer to https://mathoverflow.net/q/58934 I proved that no (proper) purely transcendental extension of an algebraically closed field is a (nontrivial) ultraproduct of fields.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly under the existence of large cardinals, the statement you claim is not true. It requires an assumption on the nonprincipal ultrafilter, which is fine when the index set is countable. I posted an answer to the linked question addressing this.

Comment: @YCor You are right, thanks for correcting me. So what survives is: If $U$ is a nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$ and $F$ is algebraically closed, then $\prod_UF$ is not a rational function field over any subfield.